# All-in-one Office installer

Tags: microsoft-office, installer, slipstream

Currently, I have individual installers for the following acquired from a few official sources (VLSC, Partner Network, MSDN, etc):

1. Office 2010 Home and Business 32-bit (OEM)
2. Office 2010 Standard with Service Pack 1 32-bit
3. Office 2010 Professional Plus with Service Pack 1 32-bit (Action Pack)
4. Office 2010 Professional Plus with Service Pack 1 32-bit (MAK / OVS / KMS)
5. Office 2010 Service Pack 1 32-bit
6. Office 2010 Service Pack 2 32-bit

As you can see, they're a little bit all over the shop and take up quite a bit of storage space, so, ideally, I'd like to have just one installer that:

1. Includes all editions (Personal, Home and Student, Home and Business, Standard, Professional, and Professional Plus)
2. Accepts any license type (retail / OEM, Action Pack, OVS, VLK, MAK, KMS, etc)
3. Includes the latest updates

I've acquired new installers for Standard, Single Image, and Professional Plus from [HeiDoc.net](http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft) (I believe this is a realtively trusted site?) which should cover all editions and I know how to slipstream updates but how do I combine the editions so it simply asks which  individual program and/or edition to install upon running Setup.exe?

I know there are channel- and edition-*switchers* but they don't seem to function as *combiners*.

I would also like to do this for Office 2013 but I assume it will be a similar process.

(Please correct me on any incorrect terminology)

**Update:**

Simply combining the extracted files of each installer results in the following 3 options displaying but it's missing all of the individual programs and a few of the editions:

[image]